# Parity password to confirm request?

Tags: password, parity-wallet

Where can I find the parity password to confirm a contract?

I want to transfer some ERC20 Tokens and cannot find the password.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the password for the particular ethereum account that you are trying to send the tokens from.  If you've lost it, the easiest way to reset it is to simply use the restore function inside the parity web interface to restore that wallet from the mnemonic seed.  You'll be able to set a new password for it this way.  You don't need to delete the wallet that you're locked out of before you restore it.